# How do I get sale_order_item table data by using injection method?

Tags: magento2, sales-order-item

I am trying to use the itemFactory to get last 30 minutes (updated_at) data from sales_order_item table , but not success. Anyone can hep to verify where I did wrong?

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory as itemFactoryCollection;



   protected $itemFactory;



  public function __construct(
        itemFactoryCollection $itemFactory
    ) {
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
    }


public function getOrderItems(): itemFactory
    {
        $orderItemCollectData = $this->itemFactory->create()->getCollection();
    
         $orderItemCollectData->getSelect()
          ->where(
                'updated_at >= ?',
                $orderItemCollectData->getConnection()->getDateSubSql(
                    new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'),
                    '30',
                    AdapterInterface::INTERVAL_MINUTE
                )
            );
        return $orderItemCollectData;
    }

$OrderItems = $this->getOrderItems();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use a `CollectionFactory` to create the collection, then use the pre-baked methods for querying.

Try injecting these :

```php
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory $itemCollectionFactory,
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime
```

Then use it like this:

```php
// 'Y-m-d H:i:s' is the MySQL timestamp format
$timestamp30MinutesAgo = $this->dateTime->date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-30 minutes'));
// ^^ You might want to drop a debugger here 
// to make sure this timestamp is what you want 

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->itemCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', [
    'gteq' => $timestamp30MinutesAgo
]);

$orderItems = $collection->getItems();
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Its work wonderful. One more question, if I want to get data from Sales_order_grid. which Collection Factory I should use? any documentation I can view the spec of each factory?

Comment: You can use `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\CollectionFactory`. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Grid/Collection.php

Comment: I am not sure of a comprehensive list for all collections. In Magento you can slap `Factory` at the end of most interfaces, models, etc... and Magento will auto create the factory for you. As far as trying to find the collection you are looking for, I usually just try to find the model I am looking for in a `ResourceModel` namespace and there should be a corresponding `Collection`.